# My 2d character gets stuck sometimes when moving as if there is an invisible wall. Is there a way to fix this?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, game-development

So sometimes when i move my character he just stops as if there was an invisible wall there. it mostly happens when i start moving in different directions. But jumping fixes it so it might be something with the floor collider. Btw I am using a tile map for my game. I set up the tile map collider and gave the collider the 2d physic material with 0.5 friction.

I tried slowing down the speed of my character a tiny bit because I thought it was something about clipping into the floor for being to fast. but it still happened after i changed the speed. I then changed the friction on the tile map collider which didn't help either

Answer (score 0):

Does your player have boxcollider2d ? If so try to change the players collider to the capsulecollider2d.

Comment: While it fixed the player stopping randomly the player now sometimes jitters up and down